# Is the number of possible $3$ element subsets of set $B$ equal to number of $3$ element selections from $B$?

Tags: combinatorics

> Is the number of possible $3$ element subsets of set $B$ equal to the ways we can choose a set of $3$ elements from $B$?

At first glance this seems to be true, but I feel like there's a catch because when choosing subsets of $B$ maybe we need to count empty set as well?

Comment: I don't think the empty set has three elements.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown of course, I thought maybe the empty set will be part of some 3 element set

Comment: Yes, if set $B$ has $n$ elements, the number of subsets with three elements is $\binom{n}{3}$.  As Lord Shark the Unknown pointed out, the empty set is not a subset with three elements.  Also, the empty set is not an element of set $B$.  It is a subset.